# How to add motion blur to numpy array

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, blur

I have a numpy array from image

So, is there a good way to do so:
`from PIL import Image
a = Image.open('img')
a = a.filter(MOTION_BLUR)`

Answer (score 12):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('input.jpg')
cv2.imshow('Original', img)

size = 15

# generating the kernel
kernel_motion_blur = np.zeros((size, size))
kernel_motion_blur[int((size-1)/2), :] = np.ones(size)
kernel_motion_blur = kernel_motion_blur / size

# applying the kernel to the input image
output = cv2.filter2D(img, -1, kernel_motion_blur)

cv2.imshow('Motion Blur', output)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

explanation you can found [here](https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/Application-Development/9781785283932/2/ch02lvl1sec21/Motion%20blur)

Answer (score 9):

draw a rotated line as kernel, then apply a convolution filter to an image with that kernel.

The code below uses opencv framework.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#size - in pixels, size of motion blur
#angel - in degrees, direction of motion blur
def apply_motion_blur(image, size, angle):
    k = np.zeros((size, size), dtype=np.float32)
    k[ (size-1)// 2 , :] = np.ones(size, dtype=np.float32)
    k = cv2.warpAffine(k, cv2.getRotationMatrix2D( (size / 2 -0.5 , size / 2 -0.5 ) , angle, 1.0), (size, size) )  
    k = k * ( 1.0 / np.sum(k) )        
    return cv2.filter2D(image, -1, k)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to apply vertical, you can use this kernel:

```
kernel_motion_blur = np.zeros((size, size))
kernel_motion_blur[int(:, (size-1)/2)] = np.ones(size)
kernel_motion_blur = kernel_motion_blur / size
```

Answer (score -3):

I would use [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html):

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('your_image')
imgplot = plt.imshow(img, interpolation="bicubic")
```